# Does DoubleClick support API url for retrieving ads?

Tags: api, advertisement-server

I have a service that I developed. This service gets parameters of a user via API url, and returns the relevant ad.

Can I use it in DoubleClick Campaign manager? (I think it's another name for DoubleClick for Advertisers).

I mean to set a dynamic urls in advertisers sites that contain relevant data for the visited user. It will be generated to the relevant ad by my service.

If I can't do it with DoubleClick, do you know another platform I can achieve it?